# Send/Email Chat Transcript to customers in Watson Assistant Chatbot

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I'm using free(lite) plan of IBM Watson Assistant exploring the possible scenarios for conversations & I'm new to this platform. I'm trying to send/email the entire chat conversations to the customers email but I could not retrieve/store/send the chat transcript along with the email. I went through many related search but cold not find the proper documentation/steps to complete the process. Can someone guide me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no system variable that holds the entire chat transscript, you would need to add and maintain it on your own. The documentation for IBM Watson Assistant has a section on [logging activity with a webhook](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-log), but it seems only available for Enterprise plans. Still, you could log the [user input](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-intent-props-example) and your response to a database via webhook or [add it as text](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-strings-append) to a (JSON) variable.

Further, depending on your app architecture, your chatbot app could manage the transcript on its own.